# 403 error When i send ajax request on Wordpress website

Tags: ajax, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

i have to create a specifif form ta register data into the database and send a mail without refreshing the page

so i create a script.js file :

```
    (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('form[name="form_result"]').on('submit', function() {
            var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
            console.log('hello');
            form_data.push({"name" : "security", "value" : ajax_nonce });
            console.log(form_data);
            // Here is the ajax petition
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : ajax_url,
                type : 'post',
                data : form_data,
                success : function( response ) {
                    // You can craft something here to handle the message return
                    alert(response);
                },
                fail : function( err ) {
                    alert("there was an error: " + err );
                }
            });
            // This return prevents the submit event to refresh the page.
            return false;
        });    
      });
})(jQuery);
```

in my function.php file i declare  has follow :

```
function javascript_variables(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>';
        var ajax_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "secure_nonce_name" ); ?>';
    </script><?php
}
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'javascript_variables' );


//AJAX REQUEST
function twentytwentychild_asset() {
    // ...
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // Charger notre script
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'twentytwentychild',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/script.js', 
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0', true
    );

    // Envoyer une variable de PHP à JS proprement
    wp_localize_script('twentytwentychild', 'ajaxurl', admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwentychild_asset');


add_action('wp_ajax_send_form', 'send_form'); // This is for authenticated users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_form', 'send_form');

function send_form(){
    // This is a secure process to validate if this request comes from a valid source.
    check_ajax_referer( 'secure-nonce-name', 'security' );
 
    /**
     * First we make some validations, 
     * I think you are able to put better validations and sanitizations. =)
     */
     
    if ( empty( $_POST["name"] ) ) {
        echo "Insert your name please";
        wp_die();
    }
 
    if ( ! filter_var( $_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
        echo 'Insert your email please';
        wp_die();
    }
 
    if ( empty( $_POST["fcPhone"] ) ) {
        echo "Insert your phone please";
        wp_die();
    }

    $to = 'test@gmail.com';

    $subject = 'Un potentiel consultant viens de faire une simulation!';

    $body  = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . '\n';
    $body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '\n';
    $body .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['fcPhone'] . '\n';

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

    echo 'Done!';
    wp_die();
     
}
```

and my template page
it's a simple form :

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form_result">
    <div id="simulation_form">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 2rem; display: flex;">
            <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
                <div class="simulation_form_q">Votre name:*</div>
                <div class="simulation_form_r">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_col-sm-8">
                <div class="simulation_form_q">Votre email:*</div>
                <div class="simulation_form_r">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_col-sm-8">
                <div class="simulation_form_q">Votre numero de telephone:*</div>
                <div class="simulation_form_r">
                    <input type="text" name="fcPhone" id="telephone" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_form" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;"/>
        <div class="simulation_form_btn">
            <input type="submit" value="calculez vos revenus">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

but when i send the Ajax request i have 403 error forbidden I don't know why i clear the cache and the cookie i use console log to debug the ajax request and it send all the data yet i have still that 403 ERROR and i don't know how to solve it

Comment: If it is returning 403, it may be related to the `check_ajax_referer()` function (nonce missing). Perhaps you could try to create your nonce using the `wp_nonce_field()` function and send it through your form, or add it to the JS data when making that AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer — how can you solve the problem:** When you call [`check_ajax_referer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_ajax_referer/), use `secure_nonce_name` as the first parameter, i.e. `check_ajax_referer( 'secure_nonce_name', 'security' )`.

### A Longer Answer

The first parameter (which is the nonce action) for `check_ajax_referer()` needs to match the first parameter for [`wp_create_nonce()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/), but in your code, they are `secure-nonce-name` and `secure_nonce_name` respectively, hence that would result in the error 403 which basically means "invalid nonce".

So make sure the names are equal or that the nonce action is correct, e.g. use `secure_nonce_name` with both the above functions:

```php
// In the script in javascript_variables():
var ajax_nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "secure_nonce_name" ); ?>';

// Then in the AJAX callback (send_form()):
check_ajax_referer( 'secure_nonce_name', 'security' );
```

### Additional Notes

- You should consider using the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) which, unlike the `admin-ajax.php`, gives a better, human-friendly message when an error is encountered while processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
check_ajax_referer( 'secure-nonce-name', 'security' );
```

Try this  instead above code

```
check_ajax_referer( $_POST['security'], 'secure_nonce_name' );
```

Comment: i change the ajax referer but i still have the  403 error

Comment: i try to use the wp debug of wordpress and i think my error maybe related to this :```Notice: WP_Scripts::localize est appelée de la mauvaise manière. Le paramètre <code>$l10n</code> doit être un tableau. Pour transmettre des données arbitraires aux scripts, utilisez plutôt la fonction <code>wp_add_inline_script()</code>. Veuillez lire <a href="https://fr.wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Débogage dans WordPress</a> (en) pour plus d’informations. (Ce message a été ajouté à la version 5.7.0.) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5313```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, first i created this in my form

```
wp_nonce_field('nader_ajax_login', 'nader_ajax_login_nonce')
```

but i had 403 error, finally solved with this in php function

```
check_ajax_referer('nader_ajax_login', 'nader_ajax_login_nonce')
```

the point is that its need to be exact same args in `wp_nonce_field` and `check_ajax_referer`